# How do I change the toolbar dynamically in Zimbra

Tags: javascript, zimbra

what is the best way to change the toolbars in Zimbra.
Zimbra does have a Toolbar for every view and we need to change it by either adding or removing buttons.

I think Zimlets are supposed to provide this functionality, but Zimlets are loaded at the end and therefore the user would see the initial buttons first. Then they would disappear and replaced. That's not really good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a way to do this with zimlets.
One just needs to create his own skin template for the toolbar and use the onShowView and initializeToolbar methods in his Zimlet to implement his buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the zimbra fire the soap for zimlet loading which is called after the loading of zimbra default componenet.

SO you are not be able to remove initial buttons first. If you want to replace those button then you have to wait for some time..